# Window manager for linux, supporting focusless windows

Tags: linux, focus, window-managers

On my arm embedded device with a touchscreen, I have a 3rd party program (program A), that creates a window which handle keyboard presses. Because of that, this window always has to have focus. This is a closed source, and I do not have options to modify it.

I need to create a window in linux, that never grabs focus. It just shows an image, some times full screen. However, I have options not to make it full screen (1 pixel less, so window below is visible.).

Right now, I am using only X server, but I can install (almost) any window manager.

1. Is there a way to create a window in X, that never gets focus? If I understand X correctly, a window bellow mouse will get focus.
2. Is there a window manager, which supports such feature?
3. Is this possible to do with with xcb or wayland?

Answer (score 0):

On Wayland, it's up to the compositor to tell the client whether it has focus or not, and which surface(s) to send key events to. So it would depend on the compositor or compositor toolkit you're using if it's possible.

KWin has an option that sounds like it does what you want. Right click the window title bar and choose `more actions -> special window settings -> accept focus`

Of the compositor toolkits, I only know the Qt Wayland Compositor API, and with that it should be possible (assuming your application can run as a Wayland client). The easiest thing would be to just show the image in the compositor using the QML APIs, or you could set `enabled: false` on the `WaylandQuickItem` or `ShellSurfaceItem` that you don't want to grab input focus.